# Example of group of order $p^3$

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number
I am trying to find an example of group of order $p^3$ that is non abelian.

I know that a group of order $p$ or $p^2$ is abelian, but how to find an example of non abelian group of order $p^3$?

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Do you care about all $p$ or are you happy with any $p$? If the latter, try with non-commutative groups of order $8=2^3$, such as the dihedral group $D_4$ or the group of quaternions.

Comment: Indeed I do care about all $p$, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using semidirect products is almost always the easiest way to construct groups that are non-abelian of a given order. In this case, look at $C_p\rtimes_\varphi C_{p^2}$.

Comment: More info at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group

Answer (score 3):

Consider  group of all 3×3 upper triangular matrices  with diagonal entries 1  and non diagonal elements in $Z_p$ then for any prime p this group is a non abelian group of order $p^3$.
Hope it works

Comment: This does work, and produces the same group as I talk about in my answer

Comment: Yeah exactly @stellaBiderman

Answer (score 2):

The simplest ones (non-isomorphic) are probably:

- the *quaternion group* $Q_8$, which is the multiplicative group of the set of $8$ elements in the quaternion skew field $\mathbf H$:
  $$Q_8=\bigl\{\pm1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k \bigr\};$$
- the *dihedral group* $D_4$ of isometries of the square, which has two generators $r$ and $s$ satisifying the relations:
  $$ s^2=r^4=e,\quad rs=sr^3.$$